# Is it OK to block my javascript files in robots.txt?

Tags: seo, google, robots.txt, googlebot

Is it OK to block my javascript files in robots.txt, or can it hurt my website SEO-wise?

Answer (score 4):

After Panda 4 update (May 2014), blocking css & js files will kill your seo.

There is a nice case study here that shows how doing that can hurt SEO :

https://yoast.com/google-panda-robots-css-js/

Nowadays Google wants to see your pages as same as users, so it is important to let him to see your client side scripts and style sheets.

Comment: This is the correct answer! View also Matt Cutts video: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=B9BWbruCiDc

Comment: Although I suspect that since it's a link in the page that is being crawled, Google will read it anyway.

Answer (score 0):

You don't state the reason to do that, so the general answer is no.

JavaScript files are not usually crawled, search engines know they are there, but they usually don't do anything with them because they don't have any content for users. So there is no need to do that from the Search Engines/Crawlers perspective.

From the perspective of normal users, it makes less sense because users don't use the robots.txt file and if they want to check your JavaScript files, they can access them directly after checking your code.

About the specific question, no, it won't hurt your SEO in any way because is basically a rule that nobody would pay attention to it.

Potentially may affect you badly if you make a mistake and block a folder that has content, but assuming you won't make that mistake, there is no benefit or drawback.

Comment: Would a search engine bot that supports/runs JavaScript still *access* (not *index*) the JS files?

Comment: You should not block JavaScript from being crawled because search engines (ie. Google) **DO** crawl (and _execute_ to a certain extent) these files and if your content is dependent on the execution of this JavaScript, in any way, then it could hurt your SEO. Matt Cutts (Google) - March 2012 - [Don't block Googlebot from crawling JavaScript and CSS](http://youtu.be/B9BWbruCiDc) @unor Yes.

Comment: Yes, they can detect and execute, for instance, AJAX request for content and follow forms activated by JS.

Comment: What if I don't want them to execute AJAX?

Comment: In any case, you can´t really block acces to anything on robots.txt. So if you want to prevent crawlers to execute the JS files, then it´s better to block them by oter meanings, like .htaccess. But be careful, that may end up on creating problems to your ranking on search engines, if you don´t mind the potential problem, then it´s ok.

Comment: @PatomaS: "if you want to prevent crawlers to execute the JS files, then it´s better to block them by oter meanings, like .htaccess." - Good bots obey robots.txt. By disallowing crawling of JS files in robots.txt you will prevent bots from executing these files.

Comment: @w3d, yes good bots do, but others don't so If I have to implement a rule, I prefer to implement it in a way that works for all of them. Plus I'm never sure if they will follow robots.txt or not, or for how long. Of course you can use the robots.txt to reduce work on the server side, assuming the "good will" of good bots, the combination is better than only .htaccess. Although in my opinion, that access shouldn't be prevented.

Answer (score -1):

It would certainly hurt your SEO for [code search engines](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Category%3aCode_search_engines).

Comment: what's a code search engine that is functional as of today? I absolutely don't want my code to be searchable.

Comment: @getbuck: I have no first hand experience; I’d guess there are countless (just like there are countless general search engines), though many probably only index FLOSS code. --- It seems that [NerdyData](http://nerdydata.com/) got some hype recently.